# Multiple Shipping Addresses in Magento with SagePay

Tags: magento, opayo

I've found this solution: http://ebizmarts.com/sage-pay
However multiple shipping support is "limited", and it says "Only Direct Protocol (with no 3DS) and Server (inFrame) Protocol are supported." I don't know what this means, or what to ask my developer!

Version: Magento 1.5.1 (will be upgrading to 1.7.1 next month)

Answer (score 1):

Magento's multiple address checkout (MAC) creates one order per delivery address, that makes a bit hard to integrate with payment methods that require redirections to 3rd. party websites. That's why support for MAC is limited.

- Sage Pay Direct with no 3DS checks. Only "direct" transactions are supported as it is not possible to redirect to the bank site for each order Magento creates. You can use Direct integration, but Sage Pay SUite Pro will force 3D Secure checks to NO.
- Sage Pay Server (inFrame). Full support here, including 3DS checks as the payment form opens inside the checkout page (in an iFrame) and all the payment process is handled by Sage Pay.

I hope this helps.

Ignacio @ ebizmarts.

Comment: Thank you. I just need a bit more clarification - are Multiple Address orders (2 or more addresses, therefore 2 or more magento orders at one time) supported under Sage Pay Direct with no 3DS checks in your Plugin? I have your plugin, but the 2nd/3rd/4th address always end up as orphaned orders.

Comment: Also, what would be the deciding factors on which method (Direct or Server) I should use?